# Installing a second instance of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to install second instance of SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition on my Windows 7 machine using a network server, local service, and my admin account.

However I keep getting the error shown below. Can somebody please let me know which user should I use?

> is not a valid login or you do not have the permission.

Comment: Did you leave any of the service accounts blank?  It seems like its complaining about a blank user

Comment: No I did not. Thank you for prompt response

Answer (score 0):

Create new alais using sql server configuration manager and use that user name to login into database

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the your username or any of the usernames that you added access for is not the same as the computer name or domain name that you are installing it on.